# Word to describe the in-depthness of something

Tags: word-usage

Is in-depthness commonly used as a word? If so, is it spelled correctly (all spell checkers I tried do not recognize it as a word)? If not, is there a word describing the same idea of something being in-depth?

An example sentence would be:

> The in-depthness of the documentation was great, as it helped in understanding the product.

Comment: Thoroughness will be good option.

Comment: ... Yes, and 'thorough' is listed as a synonym for 'in-depth'. +1 for 'commenting' rather than 'answering'.

Comment: ...what's wrong with 'depth'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Depth" and "thoroughness" could be used.  So could "comprehensiveness", although there is a mental image of breadth rather than depth.

Full Definition of comprehensive

1
:  covering completely or broadly :  inclusive

com·pre·hen·sive·ness noun

**[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/comprehensive)**

*The comprehensiveness of the documentation was great, as it helped in understanding the product.* Or you could recast it as

*The documentation was comprehensive.  This was great, as it helped in understanding the product.*